# Compute $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac2n)^{n+1}$

Tags: limits

Compute $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac2n)^{n+1}$$
The result is $e^2$.I've done this much so far:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac2n)^{n+1} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{1}{\frac{n}{2}})^{n+1} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}((1+\frac{1}{\frac{n}{2}})^{\frac{n}{2}})^{(n+1)*\frac{2}{n}}$$
Now this$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac{1}{\frac{n}{2}})^{\frac{n}{2}} = e$$

But how do I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac2n)^{n+1} = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}((1+\frac{2}{n})^{\frac{n}{2}})^{\frac{2(n+1)}{n}} = e^{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}2\frac{(n+1)}{n}} = e^2$$

Answer (score 2):

It might be useful to break up the limit as follows:

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \left ( 1 + \frac{2}{n} \right )^{n+1} \;\; =\;\; \lim_{n\to \infty} \left ( 1 + \frac{2}{n} \right )^n \left ( 1 + \frac{2}{n} \right ).
$$

If you multiply through, then what do you know about the limit of products of sequences?

Answer (score 1):

What if you take n=2m and substitute on your first equation? That may help :)

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$
L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac2n\right)^{n+1}
$$
Then 
\begin{align*}
\ln\lvert L\rvert
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}(n+1)\ln\left\lvert1+\frac2n\right\rvert \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left\lvert1+\frac2n\right\rvert}{\frac{1}{n+1}} \\
&\overset{L}{=}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{1+\frac2n}\left(-\frac{2}{n^2}\right)}{-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}} \\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2}{n^2+n}(n+1)^2 \\
&= 2\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^2}{n^2+n} \\
&= ?
\end{align*}
where $\overset{L}{=}$ denotes an application of L'Hopital's rule. Can you finish this string of equalities? Once you've solved for $?$ we have
$$
\ln\lvert L\rvert=?
$$
so that $L=e^?$.